# Date conversion is not working as expected, time always remains after conversion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

I'm trying to do the most simple of things, convert a date to a different date format but I can't seem to do it as my knowledge in ruby is practically zero.

I tried to read through [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Date.html#method-i-readable_inspect) and tried **all** of the possible `.to_formatted_s()` versions but none of them works. The time seems to always remain there no matter what. Since this date doesn't come from a `date.new()` but rather an existing object property I'm guessing this is the reason why `.to_formatted_s()` isn't working as in the example in the docs. I could be horribly wrong though.

How do I convert this date format:

```
2015-07-01 01:59:59 +0200
```

To this:

```
2015-07-01
```

My attempts were:

```
  // inv.end is "2015-07-01 01:59:59 +0200"

  inv.end.to_formatted_s(:db)
  inv.end.to_s(:db)
  inv.end.to_formatted_s(:iso8601)
```

Which all outputted `2015-06-30 23:59:59`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require 'date'
DateTime.parse("2015-07-01 01:59:59 +0200").strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

- http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime

Comment: inv.end.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') is the correct solution :)

Comment: Yeah but don't use `end` or `begin` as method or attribute names in Ruby. They are keywords and will cause syntax errors if called implicitly. So `foo.end` works. But if you try to call `end` in the `Foo` class you get a syntax error.

Comment: I'm not the one writing the backend api so I can't change it unfortunately. I'm just the frontend guy :P

Comment: Tell the backend guy he's an idiot from me :). You just don't do that, unless its your first day.

Comment: I think he's been doing it for at least 5-8 years hehe. I will let him know :D

Answer (score 1):

The above answer is correct.
If you want to perform the same date format repetitively , then create a file in initializers & write the below code:
class ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
    def my_format(options = {})
        strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
    end
end

& after the datetime object just write my_format like @user.updated_at.my_format